# spark kafka security kerberos

Tags: security, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I try to use kafka(0.9.1) with secure mode. I would read data with Spark, so I must pass the JAAS conf file to the JVM. I use this cmd to start my job :

```
    /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit -v --master spark://master1:7077    \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.conf=kafka_client_jaas.conf" \
    --files "./conf/kafka_client_jaas.conf,./conf/kafka.client.1.keytab" \
    --class kafka.ConsumerSasl  ./kafka.jar --topics test
```

I still have the same error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass java.security.auth.login.config in secure mode.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.login(Login.java:289)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.<init>(Login.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:55)
```

I think the spark does not inject the parameter *Djava.security.auth.login.conf* in the jvm !!

Comment: From personal experience, command-line options may or may not work depending on the way Spark was compiled. Did you try to hard-set `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`?

Comment: And BTW, did you try to run the code in local mode, with just `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`?

Comment: I started with spark.driver.extraJavaOptions, so it the right option. I think the authentication of kafka is in the Driver not in the executors .

Comment: It depends - in `local` mode the executors run in the same process as the driver, so they inherit the JAAS config and Kerberos tickets (and I guess that some "executor" options are not honored consistently). In YARN / MESOS mode, on the other hand, the executors run on different machines and need their own config (and their own scala/python code to bootstrap the authentification to Kafka *et al.*)

Comment: I have the same problem when I test with yarn-client. I think the spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is used when we start with yarn cluster ?

Comment: When you start *any* executor -- if you use Spark dynamic allocation, that could happen in mid-flight (e.g. start with 2 exec then scale up to 6 then down to 4 then up to 8 then stop).

Comment: I have a question :  when I use --file user_jass.conf,user.keytab hwo can I linked this with spark.executor.extraJavaOptions ??  in the workers machines I don't know where is location of user_jaas.conf

Comment: *[Corrected]* From the Spark API docs: *`addFile(path)` ... To access the file in Spark jobs, use `SparkFiles.get(fileName)` to find its download location* -- then you can call `System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.conf", ***)` before your code makes its connection attempt.

Comment: yeh it is good but the problem I need to set the path of the keytab file in the jaas file !!

Comment: So let's hope that the files are dumped in the Current Working Dir *(just as Hadoop does)*... Or if they aren't, implement some funny RegEx-based edition of the JAAS conf, to define the actual keytab path at run-time.

Comment: what's your point of view for this solution : : https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6332/how-to-read-from-a-kafka-topic-using-spark-streami.html?sort=votes .

Comment: when I use a local path /home/kafka_client_jaas.conf it work, but I need to distribute the jaas file in the same location in all workers machines !! I don’t know how executors can find the jaas when we use the option -–file .

Comment: You dont need to distribute the jaas_file on all workers. Use yarn deploy mode as client, and use /path/to/jaas.conf with files option. Spark will take files from local fs of yarn client [driver] and distribute it to all workers.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of this issue is that you have mentioned wrong property name. it should be `java.security.auth.login.config` and not `-Djava.security.auth.login.conf`. Moreover if you are using keytab file. make sure to make it available on all executors using `--files` argument in `spark-submit`. if you are using kerberos ticket make sure to set `KRB5CCNAME` on all executors using property `SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV`.

if you are using older version of spark 1.6.x or earlier. then there are some known issues with spark that this integration will not work then you have to write a custom receiver.

For spark 1.8 and later, you can see configuration [here](http://lets-do-something-big.blogspot.in/2016/09/enterprise-kafka-and-spark-kerberos.html?view=sidebar)

Incase you need to create custom receiver you can see [this](http://lets-do-something-big.blogspot.in/2016/09/advanced-spark-custom-receiver-for.html?view=sidebar)